# how to get the error log from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, logging

I intend to create a custom error page in sharepoint 2007, when error hits, the error description should store into an error log file.

Previously the method used was refering to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint....077#xx3798077xx , however it hit inconsistency error message due to having Network Load Balancer, so it route between 2 servers and caused the problem.

```
HttpContext Context = HttpContext.Current;
Exception exception;
for (exception = Context.Server.GetLastError(); 
  exception.InnerException != null; 
  exception = exception.InnerException) { }
```

The exception object got is already wrong because of the routing between servers.

Any suggestion on how to get the error log from Sharepoint? E.g: using SharePoint SDK to get the error log...

Answer (score 1):

You'll never find the right error in the SharePoint logs. There is too much multi-threaded activity logged there for you to find the error.

The right solution is to setup Client Affinity (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687542.aspx) in NLB so that your client traffic returns to the same server consistently.